# Search function not working correctly in Nautilus-Elementary?

Tags: nautilus-elementary

How do I search using Nautilus-Elementary? As soon as I click the magnifying glass, the list of files in the folder I'm trying to search disappears and tabs for SourceCode, Video and Image appear (already with some results). Changing the option that defaults to 'This week' doesn't seem to help at all either. Am I missing something seriously basic here? All I want to do is a simple search within the folder or drive I've got open in Nautilus. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug that affects 32-bit systems which has been fixed, you need to update.

**Bug #644652**: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus-elementary/+bug/644652

---

Nautilus Elementary is no longer being actively developed:  http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/nautilus-elementary-is-dead-marlin-file-browser/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, glad I'm not crazy, but shame it's a fairly showstopping bug. I'd read about Marlin but was planning to wait for a stable release; guess I'll give it a whirl after all!

Comment: Marlin is very much a sketch on the paper as of now. Its not yet available and would probably take months for us use.

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus elementary's search now uses zeitgeist which means that you can only search the data which has been previously opened, this is the reason why you see Images, videos and source codes when you click on search because you have opened them before.

So this makes the search option in the nautilus elementary meaningless IMO.

Alternatively, you can go to **Places > Search for files** for a better search or you can download [Gnome Tracker Tool](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/) from the software centre.

Comment: Does that plug into Nautilus? I didn't want to have to go to the main Search option every time I was looking for a file.

Comment: No, you'll have to goto applications > applications for tracker.